# Are these two queries technically equal to each other?

Tags: sql-server, subquery

Ran it in my query browser. I was <s>am</s> getting same results for both. But still need a confirmation.

```
SELECT 
    cs.RSCode
    , CustomerName
    , em.EmailId 
FROM 
    Customer_STN cs
    JOIN EmployeeMaster em ON cs.RSCode = em.UserName
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Confirmed_Attendance ca ON cs.RSCode = ca.rsCode
WHERE
    isConfirmed=1 
AND
    dateOfConfirmation = '2012-08-25'
```

Second query:

```
SELECT 
    cs.RSCode
    , CustomerName
    , em.EmailId 
FROM 
    Customer_STN cs
JOIN 
    EmployeeMaster em ON cs.RSCode = em.UserName
WHERE 
    RSCode NOT IN (
        SELECT 
             rsCode 
        FROM 
             Confirmed_Attendance 
        WHERE 
             dateOfConfirmation = '2012-08-25' 
        AND 
             isConfirmed = 1
)
```

EDIT: Added the `WHERE` part as Rob noticed. Not so similar any more.

Comment: You mean apart from the obvious thing that there's no filter on dateOfConfirmation or isConfirmed in the first query?

Comment: The `WHERE` you have added turns the outer join back into an inner join. You would need the rewrite in @ypercube's answer with the filter in the `ON` (and a filter in the where clause to bring back only null extended (unmatched) rows). Table definitions (including column nullability) would definitely be useful here as well.

Comment: The `WHERE` you have added makes it really hard for the 2 queries to produce the same results. Unless that `NOT IN` is `IN` in the 2nd query. Which would change the question vastly.

Comment: Also please get in the habit of affixing proper aliases to all of your column names. In the first query, while `CustomerName` is pretty obvious, how do I figure out what table `isConfirmed` and `dateOfConfirmation` come from? This can be very important to identify quickly especially since it really does matter for outer joins.

Answer (score 6):

No. But almost.

There are four things that joins do. I wrote about this at: **[JOIN simplification in SQL Server](http://msmvps.com/blogs/robfarley/archive/2008/11/09/join-simplification-in-sql-server.aspx)**

Your "`NOT IN`" (which you should be careful of, regarding `NULLs` - try using `NOT EXISTS`) won't duplicate any rows. A `LEFT JOIN` can. But consider the use of Unique Indexes/Constraints/PKs, which can help the Query Optimizer treat these as identical.

On the whole, use `NOT EXISTS` rather than `LEFT JOIN`, because `NOT EXISTS` will get treated as an Anti Semi-Join, which is slightly better than what a `LEFT JOIN / NOT NULL` does. I show this at: **[Joins without JOIN](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/rob_farley/archive/2011/10/04/joins-without-join.aspx)**

So... based on my assumption of what your queries were meant to be, the answer is:

Almost. (And how 'almost' depends on the metadata involved)

Answer (score 4):

No, they are not equivalent.

If `Confirmed_Attendance.rsCode` is not nullable, then your second query is equivalent to this one:

```
SELECT 
    cs.RSCode
    , CustomerName
    , em.EmailId 
FROM 
    Customer_STN cs
    JOIN EmployeeMaster em ON cs.RSCode = em.UserName
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Confirmed_Attendance ca ON cs.RSCode = ca.rsCode
                                           AND ca.dateOfConfirmation = '2012-08-25' 
                                           AND ca.isConfirmed = 1
WHERE
    ca.rsCode IS NULL ;
```

Without these additions, your first query may produce multiple rows (if `ca.rsCode` is not unique) or more rows than the second (if there are data with `ca.dateOfConfirmation = '2012-08-25' AND ca.isConfirmed = 1`, it will show the related results while the 2nd query will not)